# What is the name for planar curve that intersect with every line at most $2k$ time

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, reference-request

More exactly I want to know is there research in planar (closed) curve (there maybe nodes as singularities) s.t. every line in general position would intersect it at no more than $2k$ times. $k=1$ is simply the convex curve. Example for higher $k$ were algebraic curves of certain degree. Are there other general results?

Comment: I guess there is order-n curve notation, but I forget where I've read that

Comment: Is it self intersection or intersection among a family of curves?

Comment: @Narasimham I'm thinking about the intersection of a fixed curve with any line, it can be self intersecting, namely defined by a mapping S^1\rightarrow R^2. A similar term is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meander_%28mathematics%29